# Finding the sum of a given number

Tags: mysql, math

I need help, for example the given number is 55 and I want to find out on how many 10's there are, (therefore in 55 there are five 10's) and in the program it has to show the remainder (and in 55 since there are five 10's and the remainder is 5) How do i do this??

(it has to show something like this)
Enter amount:55
Number of 10's:5
Remainder:5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this you need `division` and modulo `operator`, and just a little bit a help of build in `floor` method :)

What you need to do here is next:

```
select floor(55/10) as [Numer of tens], 55 % 10 as remainder
```

Comment: thanks I didnt know my question will be answered this fast

Comment: @RhylaJaezyllBete Bete please mark it as answer if this helped you :) and yes, you are welcome

Answer (score 1):

use the modulus operator `%` like

```
select floor(55/10) as divisor, 55%10 as reminder
from dual
```

Comment: floor(55/10) that should be.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the arithmetic operators, specifically divisor and modulo: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/arithmetic-functions.html

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){

    int dividend, divisor, quotient, remainder;

    printf("Enter dividend: ");
    scanf("%d", &dividend);

    printf("Enter divisor: ");
    scanf("%d", &divisor);

    // Computes quotient
    quotient = dividend / divisor;

    // Computes remainder
    remainder = dividend % divisor;

    printf("Quotient = %d\n", quotient);
    printf("Remainder = %d", remainder);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! hope this will help me, Im slow at this kind of stuff

Comment: @Rhyla Jaezyll Bete if this helped you u can upvote by pressing the uparrow button..

Comment: This doesn't look like MySQL at all.

Comment: they simply said program

Comment: Please read the tags under the question (`mysql` `math`). If you read the other answers on the question, they are all for MySQL.